# Не включать в расчет места тега размеры вложенных элементов

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Суть в том, что при ховере тега `a` должны выводиться всплески анимацией.
При ховере всё работает корректно: всплески появляются тогда, когда я подвожу мышку именно на сам текст.
Но если я начну убирать её, то это продолжится до видимых синих рамок. Я их включил инспектором элементов в Хроме, указав там, что тег `a` в фокусе (`:focus`). 
То есть на картинке даже видно, что расчет содержимого идет даже тогда, когда у всплесков стоит `visible: hidden;`.
Можно поставить `transform: scale (0,0);`, но всё равно при выводе нужно будет ставить `(1, 1)` и это не решит проблему с убиранием мышки с элемента — всплески пропадут только тогда, когда мышка покинет именно их, а не текст в теге `а`. 
 А мне нужно, чтобы всё завязано было конкретно на тексте содержимого `a`.

Сами всплески в виде svg находятся внутри тега `a`, так сказать, "голым" svg, поэтому не разворачивал.

[image: 123]

Comment: А просто задать ребёнку `position: absolute`? Тогда место вложенных элементов не будет влиять на родителя.

Comment: Вы бы лучше воссоздали сам пример, тогда было бы легче вам помочь.

Comment: Покажите тут саму анимацию с кодом, а то с бубном сложновато скакать :)

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, дело в том, что тегу "a" и внутреннему svg уже заданы position: absolute.
Место-то и не влияет... Но когда пишешь a:hover, то при появление всплеска, занимаемое место svg (потомка) как будто плюсуется к тегу "a" (родителю). Может, есть свойство, которое это отключает?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, вот [репозиторий](https://github.com/VostokSisters/vostoksisters.github.io).

Comment: @Yuri, вот [репозиторий](https://github.com/VostokSisters/vostoksisters.github.io).

Comment: @VostokSisters This page is taking way too long to load.

Sorry about that. Please try refreshing and contact us if the problem persists.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, извини, я менял соурс, чтобы gh-pages работал) Вот ссылка: [vostoksisters.github.io](https://github.com/VostokSisters/vostoksisters.github.io)

Comment: Ваше "вот репозиторий" к вопросу не подошьёшь. По правилам сайта вам рекомендуется создать минимально рабочий пример (а не приводить весь репозиторий), а приведённый код нужно вписывать в вопрос, а не давать ссылку на сторонний репозиторий.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конкретный ответ на вопрос я не нашел... По всей видимости нельзя исключить из расчета размеров элемента размеры вложенных элементов, если размеры вложенных превышают родительские, если учитывать, что `overflow: hidden` — не решение. 
Тем не менее, я решил эту задачу просто выносом элеменов и затем уже манипулировал анимацией через селектор соседних элементов (`.class1 + .class2`), который ссылается на следующий элемент в дом-структуре. 
Получился примерно такого рода код для селектора: `a:hover + figure > .splash`, который можно прочесть так: "при ховере ссылки, выбираем сразу же следующий тег  `<figure>`, а в нем применяем стили ко всем элементам с сестренской вложенностью с классом `.splash`".